# How can I let the video playing at particular position when using jw player?

Tags: javascript, html, jwplayer

I'd like to set up the button. Then if I hit that, the video will be starting at the position 30 secs elapsed. How can I code that?

My current code is just like this

```
<div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        file: "http://example.com/video.mp4",
        title: "test",
        height: 400,
        width: 600,
    });
</script>


<button name="test" onclick="document.getElementById('myElement').currentTime = 30;">Start at 30</button>
```

Comment: you might want to use a less offensive example.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider That's true. sorry about that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference) you can use `seek()` to position the video.

```
<button name="test" onclick="jwplayer('myElement').seek(30);">Start at 30</button>
```

Comment: Reference - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference